# how to preview a youtube video thumbnail when media is selected in a form?

Tags: entities, media, files

I've created a form in which people can load a video from YouTube, DailyMotion or Viméo. I use the Media file selector widget.
When I chose a vimeo video, everything is ok, i can see the thumbnail of the video. But with YouTube and DailyMotion videos, I only see the default thumbnail icon...
How could I fix it?